# Payflow Gateway to Pay Customers

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, credit-card, google-checkout

I'm setting up a marketplace app where people can buy and sell goods while my application takes a commission. I'm ok using PayPal or Google Checkout/Wallet to accept payments from customers but I don't get how to pay the sellers their money.

Is there a way to credit user's credit card or do I need all users to have PayPal accounts in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have a huge headache paying into a credit/debit account. The best way is to either use paypal (and automate the return revenue to them) or also support (i'd do both) a checking account option. Either way, you're paying overhead. Either way merchants and customers are going to be weary until your brand is trusted. You will also need good SSL certs.

See also

http://ptmoney.com/how-to-make-a-deposit-at-an-online-checking-account/

Answer (score 1):

My $0.02:

I think you'll should carefully consider what it means to be **part of the money flow** (instead of maybe just pricing for use of your marketplace - and not get involved in the buyer/seller transaction).

Its really not just a technical consideration - realize that if you do *add yourself* to that (money/transaction) flow, that you are incurring liability?

- how would you handle returns/refunds?
- disputes between buyer/seller?
- chargebacks?
- if you are using a 3rd party (PayPal or Google Checkout), how would you handle any event that pretty much means a refund/return of monies (the 3rd party makes a policy decision)?
- similar to chargebacks, you should realize that card holders' bank can make their own policy decision as well

So while all the above can be handled technically via "some API that you find", consider what all that means to your business (service operations/fincancial operations/etc).

Comment: I agree. Maybe a user subscription model is better-- don't touch each individual transaction.